# Indefinite integral of x/(a + x ln(x))

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

My web version of mathematica (student version) can't provide an indefinite integral of
$$\frac{x}{a+x\ln(x)}$$
where a is a positive constant. Specifically, I enter

```
Integrate[x/(1+x Log[x]),x]
```

into Mathematica which only returns

[image]

I've tried the typical (beginner) analytical substitutions to solve the integral but couldn't get anywhere. I only need the integral for x > 1. Can anybody here help determine the indefinite integral?

Comment: Do you want it for 1/(a-x*Log[x]) or 1/(a+x*Log[x])?

Comment: Some functions do not have an antiderivative in terms of known functions. The [Rubi](https://rulebasedintegration.org) does not find an antiderivative either.

Comment: odomosis: I fixed that typo, thanks.

Comment: Did you have any reason to expect that it has a closed form?

Comment: No. I'm not an expert with integrals ... have no reason to expect it has a closed form.

Comment: As infinte series: $\int \frac{x}{a+x \log (x)} \, dx=C+\sum _{j=0}^{\infty } -(-1)^j a^{-1-j} E_{-j}(-((2+j) \ln (x))) \ln ^{1+j}(x)$ where: $E_j(x)$ is  exponential integral function.Code:`HoldForm[
  Integrate[x/(a + x Log[x]), x] == 
   Sum[-(-1)^j a^(-1 - j) ExpIntegralE[-j, -((2 + j) Log[x])] Log[x]^(
     1 + j), {j, 0, Infinity}]] // TraditionalForm`

Comment: See [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm) for info.

Comment: Mariusz that series can't be truncated without encumbering huge error, correct? Thus it's not "closed form", correct?